# Read emails from imap using Spring integration is not working

Tags: spring, imap, spring-integration

I am trying [an example](http://blog.solidcraft.eu/2011/04/read-emails-from-imap-with-spring.html). In the example it is mentioned like use spring-integration 2.0.3, but I got a NullPointerExcpetion and to resolve it I followed what is [mentioned here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11647547/null-pointer-exception-spring-integration-messaging). But if I use spring-integration 2.1 then I think it requires spring 3.0.

**Question:**
Is it possible to have Spring version 2.5 and have spring-integration using that read emails from imap?

The following are the maven dependencies set in my project:

```
<dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring</artifactId>
        <version>2.5.6</version>
    </dependency>
...
<dependency>
<groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
<artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
<version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-integration-mail</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.3.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

**spring-component.xml**

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
xmlns:mail="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail"
xmlns:int="http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration"
xmlns:util="http://www.springframework.org/schema/util"
xsi:schemaLocation="
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-2.0.xsd
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/integration/mail/spring-integration-mail-2.1.xsd 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util 
    http://www.springframework.org/schema/util/spring-util-2.0.xsd">


    <util:properties id="javaMailProperties">
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.class">javax.net.ssl.SSLSocketFactory</prop>
    <prop key="mail.imap.socketFactory.fallback">false</prop>
    <prop key="mail.store.protocol">imaps</prop>
    <prop key="mail.debug">false</prop>
</util:properties>

<mail:inbound-channel-adapter id="imapAdapter"
                                  store-uri="imaps://<username>:<password>@imap.googlemail.com:993/INBOX"                                    
                                  channel="recieveEmailChannel"                                         
                                  should-delete-messages="false"
                                  should-mark-messages-as-read="true"                                     
                                  auto-startup="true"
                                  java-mail-properties="javaMailProperties">
    <int:poller fixed-delay="5" time-unit="SECONDS"/>
</mail:inbound-channel-adapter>

<int:channel id="recieveEmailChannel">        
    <int:interceptors>
        <int:wire-tap channel="logger"/>
    </int:interceptors>
</int:channel>

<int:logging-channel-adapter id="logger" level="DEBUG"/>

<int:service-activator input-channel="recieveEmailChannel" ref="emailReceiverService" method="receive"/>

<bean id="emailReceiverService" class="com.mycompany.DefaultEmailReceiverUtilService">
</bean>
```

EmailNotificationTest.java

```
public class EmailNotificationTest extends
    AbstractDependencyInjectionSpringContextTests

{

public static final String SOURCE_VERSION_ID = "$Id$";

    //Who ever wants to run this testcase ,Please uncomment this method
   protected String[] getConfigLocations()
    {
         return new String[]
        { "classpath:META-INF/spring/component.xml" };
    }

public void testSimpleEmailNotification()
{

}
}
```

If I run my testcase I am recieving the following exception:

org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanDefinitionStoreException: Unexpected exception parsing XML document from class path resource [META-INF/spring/component.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/scheduling/support/PeriodicTrigger
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.doLoadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:420)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:342)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.xml.XmlBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(XmlBeanDefinitionReader.java:310)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:143)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:178)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:149)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.loadBeanDefinitions(AbstractBeanDefinitionReader.java:212)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.createApplicationContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:198)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContextLocations(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:179)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.loadContext(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:158)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSpringContextTests.getContext(AbstractSpringContextTests.java:105)
    at org.springframework.test.AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.setUp(AbstractSingleSpringContextTests.java:87)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I didn't find a simple Spring Integration --> Spring version table. Here's what you could do:

- go to https://repository.jboss.org/nexus/index.html#nexus-search;quick~spring-integration-core
- pick any version
- go to the 'Maven Dependency' tab in lower right container
- click the 'Resolve' link

You'll see immediately which Spring version is required. For example with Spring Integration 2.0.0 you'll see that it depends on Spring 3.0.5.

Comment: Thanks, the version which is matching Spring core 2.5 is Spring integration 1.0.4.RELEASE. I hope that it will not cause any issues if I use 1.0.4.